# Is powerpoint presenting?

Tags: c#, api, add-in, powerpoint, msdn

I am trying to create a powerpoint add-in with c#. I'm finding it very difficult to even find useful information on MSDN.

I'm looking for a set of API's in order to check the status.

Currently, to change slide I'm using the following code:

```
var presentation = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation;

presentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next();
```

This code works fine as long as the presentation is running. If your simply editing, then it does not work. I need to check if the presentation is running.

If someone could just point me to a useful API I will be sorted. I'm a little shocked at how poor the MSDN docs are on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If SlideShowWindows.Count = 0 Then
  ' There are no slide shows in progress
Else
  ' there's a slide show a-showing
End if
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article [How to handle PowerPoint events with Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308825). Article demonstrate how you can register for different events related to Power Point. Not exactly what you are looking for but it can help